# jquery fullcalendar control date as server date

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to set today date is server date but in `fullCalendar` it is displaying local system date as today date.

I have set server date with `gotoDate` option as following.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', currentDate);
```

but it is not working properly as i click on the today button it is displaying local system date.
please help me.

Comment: Is currentDate is getting from server side?

Comment: yes i am getting it from server side.

Comment: "as i click on the today button". That's not the same as using the goToDate method. Anyway maybe if you want fullCalendar to match your server date consistently for everything you need to set the timezone option as per your requirement? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/

Comment: @ADyson thanks, if server date is 31/10/2017 (today date) and in my local system i have set one day back (i.e. 30/10/2017). so it is giving me local system date but i want server date. is it possible with timezone?

Comment: You may not need it. It's not clear what  "it is giving me local system date" means exactly? goToDate is giving you local system date? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the current date on click of today button. Code is as following.

```
$('.fc-today-button').click(function () {
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', currentDate);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default date in fullcalendar:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/

you have to use moment plugin (which is a third party plugin and you have to include it separately in your project **before** fullcalendar)

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/

Comment: Thanks, do you have any example? i have tried this but it is not working.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the answer. The `Moment` should be inserted before fullcalenar. did you?